# Descent 2, level 24 - how to deactivate this force field?

Tags: descent-2

[image]The screenshot below shows the room through the yellow door.  One of the secret doors in the main chamber with the final boss leads to a room where you can get to the other side of the force field (i.e. the one behind the guided missiles).

How does one deactivate this force field?

Comment: Have you tried shooting a flare through the grate? I believe there us a trigger in that room that activates a secret door to the cluster bombs.

Comment: No, although you can get at the room on the other side of the force field from one of the secret chambers in the room with the main boss. It's the bit between the grate and the force field with the guided missiles that I can't figure out how to get to.

Comment: If you had asked the question about 10 years ago, I would have been able to answer you straight away as this was one of my favourite games, but alas my mind is failing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot. I opened the level in an editor and it missing a trigger. It must be a level design flaw. Both sides of that tiny room do not have triggers.

Comment: Makes sense.  Well done for actually troubleshooting the problem.